# Passing a variable from one controller method to another

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, shared-state

I'm using the CodeIgniter framework. I load a main view, which contains several tabs, which load other views in a `<div>` via AJAX. My controller class looks like this:

```
class MainController extends MY_Controller
    function main($id=0)
    {
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $this->data['info'] = $this->main_model->foo($id);
        $this->load->view('main_view', $this->data);
    }

    function tab1()
    {
        $this->load->view('tab1_view', $this->data);
    }
```

}

I load the main page by calling `mywebapp/main/123`. The `id` can be used in the `main` method and in the `main_view`. But when I click on the tab, I want to use `id` in the `<div>` in `main_view` as well. What's the best way to do this? Maybe any way to make this variable global for every method in the controller?

I load the tab using jQuery:

```
$("#div").load(mywebapp/tab1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__construct()`

```
class MainController extends MY_Controller

protected $_id;

    public function __construct()
{
        $this->_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
}

    function main()
    {
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $this->data['info'] = $this->main_model->foo($this->_id);
        $this->load->view('main_view', $this->data);
    }

    function tab1()
    {
        //available here too
        echo $this->_id;
        $this->load->view('tab1_view', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Alternately you could change this to use: `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)` which are key value pairs after `/method/controller/key/value/key2/value2`

**Example:**

```
/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male

[array]
(
    'name' => 'joe'
    'location'  => 'UK'
    'gender'    => 'male'
)
```

Comment: this sadly doesn't work for me. When I load a 'subview' with $("div").load(mywebapp/tab1)` the `MainController` gets loaded again and `$this->_id` gets overritten empty (`$this->uri->segment(2)` is tab1)

Comment: so pass it. $('div').load('mywebapp/tab1?somevar=<?=$this->_id;?>');  If some var exists, overwrite $this->_id